# r mean on subset of data updating columns for whole data

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to calculate the mean value on one column for subsets of the data, and input this mean into a new column for the whole data.

Here is some code to makes things clearer hopefully:

```
t <- data.table(Label=c(0,1,0,1,1,1), x=c("aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb"), environment=c("train","train","test","test","train","test"))
t
   Label  x environment
1:     0 aa       train
2:     1 aa       train
3:     0 aa        test
4:     1 aa        test
5:     1 bb       train
6:     1 bb        test
setkey(t,x)
t[environment=="train",avg := mean(Label),by=c("x")]

t
   Label  x environment avg
1:     0 aa       train 0.5
2:     1 aa       train 0.5
3:     0 aa        test  NA
4:     1 aa        test  NA
5:     1 bb       train 1.0
6:     1 bb        test  NA
```

The code above works except it does not update the rows where environment=="test", which is normal because I did the mean on the subset excluding those.

So I want to keep the mean on the subset, but update the avg column for all rows including the "test" ones.

So the results should be:

```
t
   Label  x environment avg
1:     0 aa       train 0.5
2:     1 aa       train 0.5
3:     0 aa        test 0.5 # average calculated with train rows only
4:     1 aa        test 0.5 # average calculated with train rows only
5:     1 bb       train 1.0
6:     1 bb        test 1.0 # average calculated with train rows only
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this is what you after

```
t[environment == "train", avg := mean(Label), by = x][, avg := mean(avg, na.rm = T), by= x]
t 

##   Label  x environment avg
## 1:     0 aa       train 0.5
## 2:     1 aa       train 0.5
## 3:     0 aa        test 0.5
## 4:     1 aa        test 0.5
## 5:     1 bb       train 1.0
## 6:     1 bb        test 1.0
```

Comment: or just `[, avg := avg[1], by = x]` for that second part

Comment: @eddie, how would you make sure that `train` is always above `test` without sorting?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably solve this question using just `data.table`, but the quickest and most convenient way for me to get the desired answer is using the [na.locf function from zoo](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf)

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
t <- data.table(Label=c(0,1,0,1,1,1), x=c("aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb"), environment=c("train","train","test","test","train","test"))

t[environment=="train",avg := mean(Label),by=c("x")]
t[,avg:=na.locf(avg),by=c("x")]
```

just to show it works i added an additional out of order test case with the label value 5 (to make the means separated by group substantially different). this is the output i got.

```
 t <- data.table(Label=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,5), x=c("aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","aa"), environment=c("train","train","test","test","train","test","test"))

 t[environment=="train",avg := mean(Label),by=c("x")]
 t[,avg:=na.locf(avg),by=c("x")]
 t
    Label  x environment avg
 1:     0 aa       train 0.5
 2:     1 aa       train 0.5
 3:     0 aa        test 0.5
 4:     1 aa        test 0.5
 5:     1 bb       train 1.0
 6:     1 bb        test 1.0
 7:     5 aa        test 0.5
```